# Can "notwithstanding" be used without a complement?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

I have checked [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/notwithstanding), [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/notwithstanding), and [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/notwithstanding), but I fail to find a conclusive answer to whether *notwithstanding* can be used without a complement. According to Merriam-Webster, it can be used as a synonym of *nevertheless* and *however*, but there are no examples to illustrate this use.

So, in short: can *notwithstanding* be used in the sense 'nevertheless', without a complement, as in the following example?

> Notwithstanding, when asked which they would choose, they all indicated X.

Comment: No, you can't use "notwithstanding" without an object - just as you can't use ***despite, regardless of, although,...*** without a clear-cut "referent". These expressions aren't syntactically the same as, for example, ***nevertheless, nonetheless, all the same, however, anyway,...*** which can all be used in a much more "general" way to introduce an assertion which somehow contradicts or "qualifies" something already written / said in the current context / conversation.

Comment: So given two assertions X and Y that might appear to be mutually incompatible, you can say *[Assertion X]. **Nevertheless**, [Assertion Y]* as two consecutive statements. But you *can't* say *[Assertion X]. **Notwithstanding**, [Assertion Y]* - you'd have to say *Notwithstanding **that**, [Assertion Y]* (where ***that*** is the "object" referring to the preceding assertion).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you! Exactly as I thought in other words :) I was confused by the Merriam-Webster entry though, according to which *notwithstanding* corresponds to *nevertheless* and *however*.

Comment: Yes, you can use the preposition "notwithstanding" without an object, as in this attested example "He intends to exercise his constitutional rights to sit on the court, [notwithstanding that the commission of inquiry has not yet made its report]. In that example the complement of "notwithstanding" is not an object but a declarative content clause. Such examples are not especially common, though.

Comment: I haven't posted an actual "Answer" because I don't know how to *explain* the two fundamentally different ways ***notwithstanding*** and ***nevertheless*** actually work syntactically. I thought there might be some easily described difference based on "parts of speech" (a term our resident expert linguist John Lawler has little time for), but when I googled [**part of speech "notwithstanding"**](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/notwithstanding/), the first link I followed tells me it can be *preposition, adverb* OR *conjunction*. Which doesn't sound like a useful categorisation to me!

Comment: @BillJ My bad! When I said *object* I meant *complement*. I've edited my question.

Comment: I suppose "declarative content clause" might be a useful concept to some people seeking to understand the usage under discussion here. But I'm a simple man, so I'd just say that the usage is functionally equivalent to *notwithstanding **the fact** that the commission of inquiry has not yet made its report* - and ***the fact*** is a perfectly ordinary "object" in this context (even if it's only ***implicitly*** present! :)

Comment: @Helen No problem. Interestingly, "nothwithstanding" can follow its NP complement, as in "[These objections notwithstanding], they pressed ahead with their proposal."

Comment: That makes what goes with *notwithstanding* more of a subject than an object.